# Hadoop Eclipse import org.apache.commons.csv cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am new in Hadoop and  I try start my 1.project. My problem is that it dont work. It error : "import org.apache.commons.csv cannot be resolved "...
It has problem with 2 imports : import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat,
                              import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord,

I try to solve it, I read some questions at stackoverflow and I download some Dependency (commons-lang 2.6 ), but it still dont work. Where is problem ?

Comment: You should try showing us some code, it would also help to know if you're using maven for the build.  And if you can assemble a working code so we can test, you will increase the number and quality of answers

Comment: ok I solve it. it want much much older version of commons -lang, that was problem